# Generic Lists c#

Tags: c#, list, generics

Is the following at all possible in c#?

I have the following but the last line won't compile, am i missing something?

```
public static void BuildGeneric<T>(List<T> l)
{
    l = new List<T>();
    var anything = new object();
    l.Add(anything);
}
```

"*The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(T)' has some invalid arguments*"

Comment: An ArrayList can do this though...

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: This method build a list, but the list can be one of two types hence it being generic - one less parameter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static void BuildGeneric<T>(List<T> l)
{
    l = new List<T>();
    var anything = new object();
    l.Add(anything);
}
```

should be this

```
public static void BuildGeneric<T>(out List<T> l)
{
    l = new List<T>();
    var anything = default(T);
    l.Add(anything);
}
```

Now you could do

```
BuildGeneric<object>(out l);
```

Since there is a discussion (comment) below about the default keyword, I thought I should include a link to it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Ohhh +1 for `default(T)` I've never seen that before.

Comment: Let me just add (for the benefit of the questioner) that this will create a list with a null in it if T is a reference type. You could use new T() instead if you put the generic constraint `new()` on T, which ensures that T must have a default constructor. If T is a value type it doesn't matter as structs in C# always have a default constructor (and you can't define your own) `default(SomeReferenceType)`yields null, `default(SomeValueType)` default constructs a value type, equal to `new SomeValueType()`

Answer (score 7):

No.

`l` can *only* hold objects of type `T`.
Your code tries to defeat the entire purpose of generics.

If you change `anything` to be of type `T`, it will work.
If you cast it to `T`, it will compile, but will throw an `InvalidCastException` at runtime unless it acutally is a `T`.

What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your function in this way:

```
public static void BuildGeneric<T>(ref List<T> l)
    where T : new()
{
    l = new List<T>();
    T anything = new T();
    l.Add(anything);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you want to create a list which contains any kinds of items. Correct? As already pointed out - this can't be done.

An appropriate approach to this would be to create a common interface for the kind of objects you want in the collection. Have all the classes you want in the collection implement this interface, and then you can have a list containing elements implementing this interface.